# Should I use Hydro or Indigo for my new project?

Tags: ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I have downloaded and tried many of the tutorials and I am sold on using ROS/Gazebo for my robotics project at my community college.

I am starting everything from scratch so I would just like some advise on whether I should install Ubuntu 12.04/Hydro or 14.04/Indigo.

I prefer Ubuntu 14.04 but I don't want to commit to Indigo if there are likely to be big problems down the road.  So basically I need to know if Indigo is stable enough for me to commit to using it.  Since I am at a school, I don't mind doing a bit of Beta testing for the new release, but I can't afford to be fighting with a lot of broken or missing features.

Thanks,
Jonathan West
Southwest Indian Polytechnic Institute.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186722/should-i-use-hydro-or-indigo-for-my-new-project?/) by [JWest](https://answers.ros.org/users/18944/jwest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2014-07-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The choice between *Hydro / 12.04* and *Indigo / 14.04* is yours.
If both distros have all the ROS packages you need for your project you basically trade better tested with longer support.

I would **not** recommend *Groovy* at this point. As soon as *Indigo* is released (which will likely be within a week) *Groovy* will be **end-of-life** and therefore not receive any kind of updates / fixes anymore.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JWest](https://answers.ros.org/users/18944/jwest/) on 2014-07-16**:
Thanks.  My project is going to be running for several years, so I would favor a long term solution.  If Indigo is about to be released it sounds like it may be my best best.

Are there currently any major features missing from Indigo that I should know about?

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-07-16**:
Well, "missing" is not the word, but important change: OpenCV - if I remember well - is no longer part of the deal (cannot really say "distribution"), having to be installed separately. This might affect your plans for the rovers.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-16**:
opencv is not longer packaged with ROS in indigo since it is available as a normal Ubuntu package on trusty, so that is not a limitation.

**Comment by [ccapriotti](https://answers.ros.org/users/18779/ccapriotti/) on 2014-07-17**:
Well, yeah, for ubuntu users and x86 architecture, it may not be a limitation, and, since the main devices here, on this question, are notebook-driven, your point is valid. Still, in a ROS-related discussion, yes, it becomes a limiting factor for several other platforms and "quick" implementation.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-18**:
@ccapriotti, fair enough, point taken that it might not be as seemless. However, you should be able to (I haven't tried this) just build and install the hydro variant of opencv, if you want even using caktin_make_isolated, and then build indigo on top.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-07-18**:
My point being opencv should not be an argument against indigo.